# fixing 504 gateway timeout issue nginx unable to load site

Tags: nginx

I had executed a select query and suddenly after that it start showing gateway timeout 504 error

root@dtest:/etc# service php-fcgi start

its has nginx and php-fcgi

[....] Starting spawn-fcgi:spawn-fcgi: bind failed: Address already in use
 failed!